# How is $f(x)=\tan(x)$ bijective for $(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$ and not for an unrestricted domain?

Tags: functions, proof-verification, proof-explanation

In other words, how can I take the inverse of $tan(x)$ when proving injectivity of $f$ like so

(Definition: injective if $f(x)=f(y)$, then $x=y$.)

$\tan(x)=\tan(y)$

$\tan^{-1}\tan(x)=\tan^{-1}\tan(y)$

$x=y$

for the interval $(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$ but not for an unrestricted domain?

Comment: It is a periodic function, thus injectivity has to fail.

Comment: Right, I can see it graphically, but how do I prove it? I need to show that tan(x)=tan(y) implies x=y, how can I safely take the inverse of tan(x) for the domain I defined above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used $\tan^{-1}$ without having showed that $\tan$ is injective !

Let $x,y \in (-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$ and suppose that $\tan x=\tan y$.

Show that it results that

$\sin x \cos y-\cos x \sin x=0$.

Now take a look at $\sin (x-y)= ??$